# Merging polygons in shapefile based on similar attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, fields-attributes, parcel

I have parcel data for several counties that contain landowner information.

Comment: What kind of file do you have ? What language do you know ? You have to edit your post if you want us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mention how many records you're dealing with; if it's not too terribly many, you could probably fix this manually without too much trouble.

One method would be to use wildcards to run a series of selects, then run a field calculate to update the values of the selected records, or populate values in a new field.  For example, you could select all records in ArcMap where "OWNER" Like '%Johnson%' then review the selected records and manually subset if necessary just to get all the ones you know are the same (since Johnson is a common name), then run a field calculate to assign them all the same value, then repeat until finished.

You could also create a lookup table, by running a "summarize" on the Owner field to get a unique list of all owner values.  Then add a "reporting value" field to that table, and do a series of manual or query selects on groups of owner values that are the same, and populate the "reporting value" field for each one.  You could then join that lookup table back to the attribute table of the layer to populate it with the new standardized values.

Creating the lookup table would also be a good first step if you want to get your unique list of values so you can automate it with a script that loops through all the values and does something like If "OWNER" = 'Johnson, S.' then "REPORTING_VALUE" = 'Johnson, Stephen', over and over and over...